# htaccess rewrite rule without changing browser url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have a multisite and I need to create a htaccess rewrite rule.

https://subdomain.mysite.com/mydir/abc.html

What I want to do is rewrite any requests like https://subdomain.mysite.com/abc.html to https://subdomain.mysite.com/mydir/abc.html but without changing the url and just for subdomain.mysite.com and not any other domain.

So first, check if domain is subdomain.mysite.com

then check if the url does not contain mydir then rewrite to the url which has mydir in it, for example https://subdomain.mysite.com/mydir/abc.html and without changing browser url.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mydir/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.html$  /mydir/$1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am getting internal server error. Also, can it be done for all urls, i.e. some wildcard rule.

Comment: @user812120, could you please do let me know if you have any other rule above this one? This should work I believe(couldn't test it though because of domain thing), let me know this one.

Comment: I put them on the very top in my .hatccess file

Comment: @user812120, could you please do let me know which sample/example url you are hitting eg--> `http://localhost:80/abc.html` like?

Comment: So for example, I am using this in my browser https://subdomain.mysite.com/abc.html and I expect to see the contents from https://subdomain.mysite.com/mydir/abc.html  without changing browser url. Please note that subdomain.mysite.com/mydir/abc.html  is working OK and displays fine but when I place the htaccess rules, both urls don't work.

Comment: @user812120, I am sorry there was a typo in rules, could you please check them now and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: @user812120, Also Please share your htaccess rule file in your question, looks like its closed with "need more focus" comments. Sharing efforts is highly encouraged on SO.